# NSProgressIndicator in NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsprogressindicator, nstablecellview

I have an NSTableCellView subclass that contains an NSProgressIndicator.

I have it all updating and animating properly, however it remains greyed out. I suspect this is a view loop issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it enabled? What makes you suspect it has to do with the view loop?

Comment: Thanks for responding @tim, it is enabled. It is greyed out as if the window is not the front view. A similar problem was experienced by someone at this link, although the fixes suggested here don't help me: [cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/160934-progress-bar-on-front-nspanel-is-grey-not-blue.html)

Answer (score 4):

NSProgressIndicator will only appear blue if it's on the key window.
If your window isn't the key window you can send it that message `[myWindow makeKeyWindow]`
Window's without title's or resize bars may not respond to that message, so you may need to subclass your window and override
`- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow{return YES}`.
This was a problem I ran into with the tint color of an nsprogressindicator on a sheet.
The doc's say to never invoke this method directly.. `[myTitlelessWindow becomeKeyWindow]` but you can use it to confirm the problem before subclassing your window.

Comment: I also just ran into the problem that my progress indicator in a sheet was grey instead of blue. Your hint solved my issue: simply enable the title bar on the sheet window.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Solved my problem too.